# Why is there an error when I try to run matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, compiler-errors, package

I'm currently taking an online course and wanted to practice using the Matplotlib package in python. Here is the code I'm working with on my file.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

year = [1950, 1970, 1990, 2010]
pop = [2.519, 3.692, 5.263, 6.972]

plt.plot(year, pop)
ply.show()
```

I've already installed it using pip as such in the same directory:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

However, when I try to running `python3 matplotlib.py` it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ipmiruek/myPython/matplotlib.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/Users/ipmiruek/myPython/matplotlib.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'; 'matplotlib' is not a package
```

I made sure to check that pip was updated as well as the directory so I'm not sure why it isn't working. Is there something wrong with the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't name your Python file the same as packages you are trying to import.

Comment: try running `pip list` to check if the packages you need are properly installed